# Jenkins agent logs to STDOUT of docker aws eks container - is it possible?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, amazon-eks

I'm starting up jenkins agents in aws eks fargate containers using kubernetes jenkins plugin
I'm running python scripts as a job. I would like to see all print statements from python script to show up in the container log.
At present the logs show up only in jenkins master and not in container logs

Could it be due to

```
Nov 27, 2022 7:45:14 AM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 3077.vd69cf116da_6f
Nov 27, 2022 7:45:14 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
Nov 27, 2022 7:45:14 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
```

that I'm not able to see STDOUT/STDERR logs on container logs?

Can I set global environmental variables  JAVA_OPTS or JENKINS_JAVA_OPTS to achieve the same?

If so what values should I set..

refer: https://github.com/jenkinsci/remoting/blob/master/docs/logging.md

Please help Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution or workaround to this? Facing a similar issue

Comment: Unfortunately no. The workaround was to directly write to cloudwatch logs from the container itself i.e python script level